# How to convert a Map<String,List<String>> to Map<String,Set<String>> using forEach operation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I want to convert a `Map<String,List<String>>` to `Map<String,Set<String>>` for optimized search. I came up with the below traditional approach.

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : this.mapWithList.entrySet()) {
        Set<String> hSet = new HashSet<>(entry.getValue());
        this.mapWithSet.put(entry.getKey(), hSet);
   }
```

I am wondering how can I do it using `forEach` in **Java 8**.

Also, with the `forEach` lambda, will it be any better with the code performance?

Answer (score 5):

> will it be any better with the code performance?

No, it'll not. **Iterative** solutions are usually more performant.

> how can I do it using `forEach`

There's a special operation `collect()` in the **Stream API** that is meant to populate a *mutable container* (e.g. `Collection`, `StringBuilder`, etc.) with the contents of the stream pipeline. Usage of `forEach()` for that purpose is highly discouraged by the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects). Consider utilizing `forEach()` only as a *last resort*, when there's no other way to achieve that.

To do that with `collect()`, first, you need to create a *stream of entries*.

Based on each *entry*, a *new entry* has to be created, `map()` operation is utilized for that purpose. Static method `Map.entry()` is used to instantiate a new entry.

And then apply the terminal operation `collect()` by passing `Collectors.toMap()` as parameter, which creates a ***collector*** (*object responsible for placing the stream elements into a mutable container, a **map** in this case*) based on the two provided *functions* (for *keys* and *values*).

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,List<String>> mapWithList =
            Map.of("1", List.of("1", "2", "3"));

    Map<String,Set<String>> result =
       mapWithList.entrySet().stream()
                  .map(entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey(),
                            new HashSet<>(entry.getValue())))
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                            Map.Entry::getValue));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output**

```
{1=[1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: for `Map.Entry::getKey` and `Map.Entry::getValue` I am getting `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`. I am using this piece of code in a public constructor, which is not static. Also `Map.Entry` doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Conquistador Seems like a type mismatch (compilation errors with method references aren't very helpful). Take a look carefully at the types (resulting variable and source).  I've provided a complete runnable example in the answer.

Comment: @Conquistador If didn't find the cause of error, place these lambdas instead of method references `Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue())` a then read the compile error - it'll be more informative.

Comment: @Conquistador `Map.Entry doesn't seem correct` - `Entry` is a nested interface that recedes inside the `Map` interface. `Map.Entry` - is a correct syntax to refer to it.

Comment: There’s no need for this `map` step. Just use `mapWithList.entrySet().stream() .collect( Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> new HashSet<>(entry.getValue())));` Note that the `Map.entry(…)` method requires Java 9, but as said, the `map` step is obsolete anyway.

Comment: @Holger I know that. When I realized that `map` operation can be eliminated, I spotted an answer that differs in code only with that part. I think it's not a fair play to turn another person's answer onto a duplicate by doing this change, so I decided to leave it is. And I think this minor issue doesn't spoil the overall value of the message that my answer was intended to convey.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> inputMap = new HashedMap<>();
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("a1");
        a.add("a2");
        inputMap.put("a", a);

        List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add("b1");
        b.add("b2");

        inputMap.put("b", b);

        System.out.println(inputMap);

        Map<String, Set<String>> resultSet= inputMap.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> new HashSet<>(e.getValue())));

        System.out.println(resultSet);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

one line solution using gson! (or any other JSON serializer)

```
Map<String, Set<String>> result = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(otherMap), Map.class);
```

both maps have the same JSON representation. think outside the box ;)